# Question on maxTotal and maxIdle in Apache Commons Pool 2?

Tags: apache-commons-dbcp

I'm using the Apache Commons Pool 2 implementation to have object pool mechanism for my application.

Below is my configuration to create pool

```
    PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, null);
                poolableConnectionFactory.setPoolStatements(poolPreparedStatements);
                poolableConnectionFactory.setValidationQuery(testConnectionSql);
                poolableConnectionFactory.setDefaultReadOnly(Boolean.TRUE);
                poolableConnectionFactory.setDefaultAutoCommit(Boolean.TRUE);
                poolableConnectionFactory.setDefaultTransactionIsolation(-1); 
                poolableConnectionFactory.setDefaultCatalog(null);

    GenericObjectPool connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool(poolableConnectionFactory);               
    connectionPool.setMaxTotal(4);                       
        connectionPool.setMaxIdle(2);    
        connectionPool.setTestOnBorrow(false);
        connectionPool.setTestOnReturn(false);
        connectionPool.setTestWhileIdle(false);
        poolableConnectionFactory.setPool(connectionPool);       
        dataSource_ = new PoolingDataSource(connectionPool);
```

But, v$session shows 13 in DB and below values in log. I have set maxtotal as 4, but it's crossing the limit. can someone help here to understand?

getMaxIdle() -- 3, getMaxTotal() -- 8, getNumIdle() -- 3, getNumActive() -- 0

Comment: Have you deployed multiple instances of the application. For example, if you have four instances running, then there could be 4*4=16 connections possible.  If not, if you have not setup your connection release code appropriately, then it is possible that the connection stays without being released. And the commons pool while trying to ask for fetch a connection when all the idle connections are not available, then might keep creating newer ones.

Comment: Only one instance is running. In log, i see idle connections available and I am borrowing that object and returning back to pool. Also, I have set maxtotal as 4. But still, connection count is growing more than this in database. Any idea ?

Comment: Probably add some log statements to make sure its being released. Also, check if the connection is from the same server or is it something else ( like a query client or so )

Comment: ok. Thanks. So, even if we set maxtotal as 4 and if no connections are available to use then dbcp will create new connections ? I mean more than 4 ? dbcp won't restrict to open new connections more than 4 ?

Comment: also, is it possible to know what's happening inside dbcp ? to display debug statements whether connection is new or using old one, releasing or not etc.. ?